# Eliminating white space at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

Originally I had a background image that appeared as a gradient background. Wanting to have a solid black backgound I removed link to background image/repeat x. The result is a large white space at bottom of page. I have searched quite a few answers to this common problem but none have helped me figure this out.

This is an .php site so if there is an html .div then I cannot find it but in css stylesheet it just reads as #top-bg with background: #000000

I have tried adding in height: 100%; not sure where to adjust margins as recommended by some sites. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some example code and/or demo somewhere would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

```
body, html{
    padding:0!important; 
    margin:0 !important;

    background:#000;//is this what you want?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that immportant and doing it as a css reset on * is what got me going!

Answer (score 0):

for start have you think to remove defaukt browser padding and margin?

```
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also, where is define your background?

- in your first div?
- in your body?
- in your HTML ?

for better, background was define in your body tag :

```
body{
    background-color: #FCC; /* for test */
}
```

If you have no padding, no margin, this code working for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body, html {

background:#000;
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0


}
```

Comment: There were 2 separate sections above top-bg. One named html and the other body. Both already had magin 0 and padding 0 so I added background and height as you suggested above and it worked!                                                                                                                                  Thank you SO much!

Comment: Glad I could help, body and html does have 100% height by default we need to set it. Also please mark my answer as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  background:#000;
}
```

This was sufficient for me to remove white space.