# Random white space at bottom of page but only on mobile

Tags: html, css

Hi I have looked at several stackoverflow questions on how to remove white space from a webpage (see selection below) but noone of the solutions given had any difference for me. The werid thing is that the whitespace only shows up when I look at my site on my mobile. The site in question is: http://moduleplanner.github.io/ and its corresponding github repo is: https://github.com/Moduleplanner/Moduleplanner.github.io

Thanks for the help. :)

[Huge White Space At Bottom Of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512865/huge-white-space-at-bottom-of-page)

[Eliminating white space at bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861524/eliminating-white-space-at-bottom-of-page)

[CSS White Space At Bottom of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499997/css-white-space-at-bottom-of-page)

[Strange space at bottom of page on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679311/strange-space-at-bottom-of-page-on-ios)

[current state of whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSA4i.png)

Comment: can you provide some code, maybe screenshots of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your CSS on the .degree element, specifically the `absolute` positioning. For mobile, change the css to the following;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
 .degree{
   min-width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
}
```

Or, even better, the following;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
 .degree{
   min-width: 100%;
   position: static;
 }
}
```

### Update

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
 .degree{
   min-width: 100%;
   position: static;
 }

 .div.degree div.course{
   width: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the white has reduced considerably, I have moved some things around and it now lookslike this: 
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xFtPfGZ1mLMTRWWFhBV1FtYlk/view">here</a>

Any ideas on how to get rid of it? thanks.

Comment: @AdamPohl Can you post that image in your original question? Images won't display in comments, and that link produces file not found as it's google account protected.

Comment: There you go, click on the `current state of whitespace` link.

Comment: Ah, okay, not much I can do from that image. Have you got an updated link to the code?

Comment: Here is a link to my fork of the repo, have a look at the last commit to see what I have done. https://github.com/Huaraz2/Moduleplanner.github.io/tree/mod-code

Comment: Sorry, I meant a currently running live version of the code so I can view the page in a browser. I've scanned your git and nothing sticks out.

Comment: The issue is now with `div.degree div.course`, you have a width set to 350px. Change this to max-width:100% in the media query and `width: auto;`, you should be golden. See my updated answer.